# How to approximately determine grouping of data points

Tags: math

I have several data points( like [x, y, r] ),  x, y is position info, r is its value mapping to radius.

The user case is when we draw those data points on the chart, sometimes many data points will overlapped, so I just want to merge them into a big single data point.
What I want to do is find a way to approximately determine which points can be group together, intuitively and generally, the data point which has great overlap area(or very close to each other) should merge together, but I do not know how to determine that in a fast way( I do not need the very precise calculation way to compare the sum of their radius larger than the distance between them).

What I want just like

```
if  V1<( Math.abs(x1-x2)+Math.abs(y1-y2) )<V2 
then these two points probably need merge.
```

something like that. But I am not sure what could be the reasonable value for V1 and V2

Comment: this might be better on math SE https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Stedy Originally I try to think it as a mathmatical way, but then I realize that when I draw the chart, it can not allow me to do heavy calculation, so I decide that it should be a humiliation to math guy if I post this in Math section. Cos this is really an engineering issue rather than a math question